# Visual Studio C++ Debug DLL containing static library

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have an C++ DLL project with some breakpoints within it. These breakpoints hit correctly. This project references other static C library. Yesterday the debugger was able to stop at breakpoints in that lib but surprisngly today it says `"no symbols have been loaded for this document"`. Anyone had such a problem before?

Comment: ***Anyone had such a problem before?*** Many times. Did you accidentally change a file in the dll? If the timestamp of any of the source files is newer than the dll your breakpoints will not work.

Comment: I verifed timestamp multiple times - it is certainly ok. I am also sure I am attaching to correct applcation (the logs from DLL match the application state).

Comment: was the code compiled today without the `-g` parameter on both the compile and link steps?   Is the source code visible to the debugger for the library?  BTW: which document is the debugger stating that it cannot find the symbols?  The library, the source code, or both?  Is the debugger being run from some other directory than where the source code for the library is located?  Have you tried something like the `load symbols` command on the library?

Comment: Normally Visual Studio tells each dll it can not load the symbols for in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

The static library needs to be built with debug symbols, and also named pdb file.  This should sort out your problem.